# Woocommerce WC API callback for custom payment gateway don't work for me

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, callback, gateway

I'm actually writing a custom plugin to connect a payment gateway to Woocommerce, and I've been stuck on a problem for several hours:

I cannot get the callback of the payment processing.

I googled a lot to find an issue but no success yet.

The environment is as follows:

- Site on a dedicated server - Ubuntu 12.04 ;
- PHP 7.1 ;
- WordPress 5.3.2 ;
- Woocommerce 3.8.1 ;
- A lot of plugins are loaded too ;

My class look like this:

```
    add_filter('woocommerce_payment_gateways', 'woogatewaypro_add_gateway_class');
    function woogatewaypro_add_gateway_class($gateways){
        $gateways[] = 'WC_Gateway_Pro';
        return $gateways;
    }

    add_action('plugins_loaded', 'woogatewaypro_init_gateway_class');

    function woogatewaypro_init_gateway_class(){

        class WC_Gateway_Pro extends WC_Payment_Gateway{

            public function __construct(){

                global $wpdb;

                global $woocommerce;

                $this->id                   = 'woogatewaypro';
                $this->icon                 = '';
                $this->has_fields           = true;
                $this->method_title         = 'Gateway Pro payment gateway';
                $this->method_description   = __('Allow payment from Gateway Pro gateway.','woogatewaypro');

                $this->supports = array(
            'products',
                    'subscriptions',
                    'subscription_cancellation',
                    'subscription_suspension',
                    'subscription_reactivation',
                    'subscription_amount_changes',
                    'subscription_date_changes',
                    'subscription_payment_method_change',
                    'subscription_payment_method_change_customer',
                    'subscription_payment_method_change_admin',
                    'multiple_subscriptions'
                );

                $this->init_form_fields();

                $this->init_settings();
                $this->title            = $this->get_option('title');
                $this->description      = $this->get_option('description');
                $this->enabled          = $this->get_option('enabled');
                $this->testmode         = 'yes' === $this->get_option('testmode');
                $this->private_key      = $this->testmode ? $this->get_option('test_private_key') : $this->get_option('private_key');
                $this->publishable_key  = $this->testmode ? $this->get_option('test_publishable_key') : $this->get_option('publishable_key');

                /* some code... */

                add_action('woocommerce_api_'.strtolower(get_class($this)), 'woogatewaypro_payment_callback');

                add_action('woocommerce_api_woogatewaypro_cancel_payment', array($this, 'woogatewaypro_cancel_payment'));

                add_action('woocommerce_api_woogatewaypro_payment_ko', array($this, 'woogatewaypro_payment_ko'));

                add_action('woocommerce_api_woogatewaypro_payment_ok', array($this, 'woogatewaypro_payment_ok'));

                add_action('woocommerce_update_options_payment_gateways_'.$this->id, array($this, 'process_admin_options'));

                add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'payment_scripts'));

                /* some code... */

            }

            public function init_form_fields(){

                /* some code... */

            }

            public function payment_scripts(){

                /* some code... */


            }

            public function process_payment($order_id){

                /* some code... */

            }

            public function woogatewaypro_cancel_payment(){

                wp_redirect(get_permalink(get_option('woocommerce_checkout_page_id')).'?woogatewaypro=cancelled-payment');

            }

            public function woogatewaypro_payment_ko(){

                wp_redirect(get_permalink(get_option('woocommerce_checkout_page_id')).'?woogatewaypro=payment-ko');

            }

            public function woogatewaypro_payment_ok(){

                /* some code... */

                wp_redirect(get_permalink(get_option('woocommerce_checkout_page_id')).'?woogatewaypro=payment-ok');

            }

        }

    }

    function add_wc_gateway_pro_gateway($methods){

        $methods[] = 'WC_Gateway_Pro';

        return $methods;

    }

    add_filter('woocommerce_payment_gateways', 'add_wc_gateway_pro_gateway');

    function woogatewaypro_payment_callback(){

        mail('user@mydomain.tld','Check callback','Enter func');

        // wp_die();
        exit;

    }
```

What I'm doing wrong?

I tried to place my woogatewaypro_payment_callback function in my class, but it doesn't work.

My URL to callback is like this:

```
    if('' == get_option('permalink_structure')){
        $callback = site_url().'/?wc-api=WC_Gateway_Pro';
    }else{
        $callback = site_url().'/wc-api/WC_Gateway_Pro/';
    }
```

I look the logs on my server, and the data seem to be posted: I get 200 status with POST.

When I try to access the function by GET, I still have a 1 on a blank page.

Could some plugin(s) create the problem?

Thanks in advance for your help ;).

Comment: Hi, I'm still on my problem: I use WP Cerber Security to protect my site, and if I see the activity on Wp Cerber Security, the plugin does not block the request to wc-api/WC_Gateway_Pro/ and the POST data are in 200 status.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and this is what works for **WooCommerce 2.0+**

```
 //register the callback hooks which we will use to receive the payment response from the gateway
add_action( 'woocommerce_api_custom_gateway', array( $this, 'payment_callback'));
```

The callback link can be accessed as **http://yoursite.com/wc-api/custom_gateway/**

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Take the name of your payment gateway class "gateway_class" and append  "woocommerce_api_" to the action - create a public method in that class which is the callback function and do your stuff. This is very unclear in the WC docs and should be more clear.. in fact the paypal example they give you is just wrong and not what is in the actual paypal code.

Answer (score 1):

After reading again my cde, I detected I have missed something to correctly declare my add_action() on callback function. SO it look like this now:

```
    add_action('woocommerce_api_'.strtolower(get_class($this)), array($this,'woogatewaypro_payment_callback'));
```

But it not works yet.

I'll try to install a new WordPress to test on a fresh environment, because I really don't understand why it doesn't work.

I hope a "Woo'pro" will pass here to help me a little :).

Answer (score 0):

I'm still on my problem (I'm going crazy...).

I use WP Cerber Security to protect my site, and no problem with it: WP Cerber Security allows posting to wc-api/WC_Gateway_Pro/, and the request is in 200 status.

The fact is that the callback function isn't executed: I don't receive any mail. I tried to save a string in the debug.log file of WordPress (debug set to true), and no log was saved.

I have read and reread all the topics to build a custom payment gateway for Woocommerce, and I don't understand what's the problem with my code: everything seems to be good in the code construction, but no possibility to execute the callback.

The WC_API execute correctly the cancel, ko and ok functions of my class, but not the callback function (why?).

Must I activate any setting on Woocommerce?

If someone has had the same problem or has an idea to solve this problem, I will be very grateful :)

Thanks a lot for your replies ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but it was due to permalink setting. You can go without Woo's way, but this other way as last option:

```
add_action(
    'init',
    array( $this, 'successfull_callback' )
);
```

Then inside the callback you check the URI and proceed...